# How to fix the resizable area of button (image) in Android Studio being bigger than the button itself?

Tags: android, adobe-xd

**!!Beginner alert!!**

I designed my app in Adobe XD. Now I started to introduce the design in Android Studio. However, whenever I use a resource from the resource manager and drop it in the designer, the resizable area is way bigger than the image which i think will affect the clickable area of it. Everything looks good in Adobe XD, the resizable area is the border of the button. How can I do this in Android Studio? I will attach images below. Help is greatly appreciated.

[How it's supposed to look (the look in Adobe XD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZoQ.png)

[The resizable area of the button in Adobe XD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrC1m.png)

[The resizable area of the button in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN27z.png)

How can I make Android Studio have the same resizable area as Adobe XD?

I implemented the XML code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".Dashboard">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/resmonevo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/red_gradient_line" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/dashboard" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView14"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle_210" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView18"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle_221" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView15"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/welcome_" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView14"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/how_are_you_today" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView20"
    android:layout_width="21dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView15"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView15"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_outline_24px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView19"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView18"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="351dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle_187"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-39dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="158dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The XML code for the most recent button is :

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="351dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle_187"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-39dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="158dp" />
```

[Here is how my mess looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvFNT.png)

Comment: Kindly share the code, so that we can help you with an exact solution.

Comment: @KamalNayan i edited the post and added the XML code. I kindly appreciate it if you could check it out!

Answer (score 0):

**The problem what I can figure out is that you are using static size in width**
I will suggest you to use Linear layout as parent and inside it have a Image view as child because you are statically defining the width of image view.
so try something like this:

**Kindly use imageView in your case I have used MaterialTextView just for an instance**

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cantata_one"
        android:text="Email"/>




    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"
        android:id="@+id/layout_recycler_all_cust_email"
        android:fontFamily="@font/capriola"
        android:textColor="#706E6E"
        android:text="Email "/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and in the above code, you can see i have assigned `weightsum` to the LinearLayout and accordingly wait to it's children so you should try this. This will make your UI Flexible according to the device size and in the   `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` you can use your value like 350DP or something else.